# Lattice definition maths

Tags: notation

For   $ N  \in  \mathbb{Z} $, I've known that $$ \mathbb{Z} /N  =\left\{ \dots, - \frac{2} {N} , -\frac{1} {N}, 0, \frac{1} {N} , \frac{2} {N}, \dots  \right\} . $$
So, what is
$ \mathbb{Z}^{2}/N?$
Is it correct that $$ \mathbb{Z}^{2}/N =\left\{ (a_1,a_2) \mid a_1, a_2 \in  \mathbb{Z}/N \right\}. $$
I have searched with keyword "lattice definition maths", by it was about Lattice (order)...

Comment: You want Lattice that's a "discrete subgroup", so [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(discrete_subgroup)).

Comment: @Mark Thank you, I'm reading it now.

Comment: Unfortunately, that article isn't the most comprehensible to a layman.  If you know about linear algebra/vector spaces, [this](http://www.math.ku.dk/~kiming/lecture_notes/2005-2006-algebraic_number_theory/lattices+log_units.pdf) pdf seems at least comprehensible (the first section at least).

Comment: Hello @Mark, think that $$ \mathbb{Z}^{2}/N =\left\{ \frac{(a_1,a_2)}{N}  \mid a_1, a_2 \in  \mathbb{Z} \right\}. $$ A  $ \mathbb{Z}$ basis of this lattice is $ \{(1/N, 0), (0, 1/N) \}$. Is it true? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that appears true. Note that $\mathbb{Z}^2/N$ as you describe it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ under the map $\phi(a,b) = (Na,Nb)$.  So, if it's conceptually to think of your lattice as $\mathbb{Z}^2$, this is well justified.